Probability that a Markov Process will End
I need help trying to make sense of the following solution on YouTube for a Markov Process. The video in question is Data Science Interview Walkthrough, Probability Question Set 3 by Mac Strelioff.
It's about the first question in the video and here it is:
Your interviewer invites you to play a card game. In this game, there are three cards–one labeled “1,” one labeled “2,” and one labeled “0.” On each round, you draw a card. Initially, you’re asked to play one round. However, the number that you draw is added to the number of rounds you must play. What is the probability that this game ends?
In essence, the solution given is "$p_d$ represent the probability of kind of this (circled in blue) whole process, that the game will be done" (at 1:50), whereby
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
    p_d &=& p_0+p_1p_d+p_2(p_d\cdot p_d) \\
    &=& p_0+p_1p_d+p_2p_d^2 \\
    p_2p_d^2+(p_1-1)p_d+p_0 &=& 0 \\
    p_d^2+-2p_d+1 &=& 0 \\
    p_d &=& 1.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
See figure. So here is where I am not really understanding:

What would be a proper definition of $p_d$?

What does $p_d$ really represent, is it that we will end the game or is it the probability we will repeat another round of the game? I don't quite get this part from the explanation starting at 1:50.

$p_d$ turns out to be $1$, and the interpretation is that the game will end, so $p_d$ seems to be representing the probability that the game will end, but how is $p_d$ associated with the whole game (the blue circle; see 1:50)?

How do we rigorously make sense of the equation $p_d=p_0+p_1p_d+p_2(p_d\cdot p_d)$?


Please be as rigorous as possible and noting that I have not learned Markov processes rigorously before.

Additionally, I was trying to write down the stochastic matrix associated with this game, but to no avail (I can't quite get what the probabilities appearing as entries of the matrix would represent). I would appreciate an answer and some explanations. I personally think being able to write down the stochastic matrix and interpret its properties is a much better way to think about the problem.
Thanks in advance!

A much simpler way to think about this is as a random walk on $\mathbb{N}$. The current state is the number of rounds left to play and the update is to subtract $1$, then add $0$, $1$, or $2$ with equal probability. The probability that the game ends is just the probability that the number eventually hits $0$. This is then a symmetric random walk in one dimension and therefore it returns to $0$ in finite time with probability $1$. That is more or less what is shown in this solution

The kind of process you are looking at is called a branching process. Loosely speaking, this process models objects (say bacteria) which divide into some number of copies of themselves.
I’m not entirely sure what the blue circle represents exactly, but the correct interpretation of $p_d$ is that it is the probability the game ever ends.
The key observation is that because of the assumption that each card pull is independent of the others, we can say the following:

If we draw a 0, then the game ends
If we draw a 1, then we basically “start over”
If we draw a 2, then we now have a “bank” of two rounds to play. If we consider all the rounds played until this number reaches 1 for the first time, then that can be considered a copy of the branching process. From that point, we have to finish a second copy to get back down to zero. In other words, if we draw a 2, we create two subgames, and the overall game ends if and only if both subgames end.

If we let $A$ be the event the game ends, and let $X$ be a random variable recording the result of the first draw, then we can summarize the above as
$$p_d=\mathbb{P}(A)=\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(A|X=0)}_{=1}\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(X=0)}_{=p_0}+\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(A|X=1)}_{=p_d}\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(X=1)}_{=p_1}+\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(A|X=2)}_{=p_d\cdot p_d}\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(X=2)}_{=p_2}=p_0+p_1p_d+p_2p_d^2$$
Solving this with $p_0=p_1=p_2=1/3$ gives $p_d=1$. Here we were lucky since there is only one root. In general, the polynomial $p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2$ is called the generating function of this process, and $p_d$ is the smallest fixed point in $[0,1]$ (note $1$ is always a fixed point). This can be nicely extended to cases where there are higher card numbers, or unequal probabilities.
